# How to make one element in a list taller than others when the list is equally spaced and center>

Tags: html, css

I have a footer `nav` that has a `ul` and several `li`s. Currently the nav is stuck to the bottom of the page, with the `li`s spread evenly across the bottom of the page.

I want to be able to make one of the `li`s, taller than all of the others.  However, when I try to do it now, by increasing the height of that specific `li` element, it either just raises the entire `nav` or does not change.  Any ideas?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Le7fdkc/)

and my code:

**HTML:**

```
    <article class="main home">
        <img class="heroLogo" src="media/TM-Logo-4.png">
            <nav>
                <div class="menuIcon"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sleep</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><div id="tm">CHANGE MY HEIGHT</div></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Relax</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Party</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </article>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    width: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    font-size: .7em;
}

nav ul, nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 auto;
    top: auto;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    background-color: #FBF6F1;
    padding: 8px;
}

nav li, .current {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 12.5%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(odd) {
    border-left-color: #9AD5E6;
    border-right-color: #9AD5E6;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid; 
}

a {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #9AD5E6;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid; 
}

.current {
    height:2em;  /* Doesn't change anything */
}
```

Comment: if you change the height of li then it effects on nav

Answer (score 0):

Right, that's how list items are displayed. You can use other means to reproduce the desired effect, like adding some padding :

```
nav li.current {
    padding-top:2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3mqgoq4/

Or keep the text vertically aligned...

```
nav li.current {
    padding:2em 0;
    position : relative;
    top : -2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3mqgoq4/1/

Comment: he want to increase height so that he can use the sapce check his code not fiddle . this is what happen then i increse the text size http://jsfiddle.net/x3mqgoq4/2/

Comment: The solution relies on setting the display of the `li` to inline.  However, to keep them centered they need to be `inline-block` which I think prevents your answer from working correctly.

Comment: `li`s should be `display : list-item` not `inline-block`

Comment: Will this fix the problem, I am not sure how to implement this.  All the solutions I have found online use `inline-block`

Comment: There is nothing to implement. `display : list-item` is spec default for `<li>` tags. Just don't override it :)

Answer (score 0):

If for instance the height of the nav is 60px and the current li height height 65

Do something like:

**Nav**

```
height: 65px; /* Its original height plus 5 */
```

**Nav Li normal**

```
height: 60px; /* leaving 5px room for height increment */
```

**Nav li current**

```
height: 605px; /*  Normal state height plus 5 and there wont be a problem */
```